# Best practices for spacing regarding fractions and roots?

Tags: spacing, best-practices

My problem is that I am about to write a longer mathematical text, and it will be filled with integrals. Integrals tend to be filled with pesky fractions, square roots and what not.

Personally I feel like LaTeX is spacing things "wrongly" I prefer to have more space in my fractions, and a tad more space after the square roots. Look at the comparison below. The difference is small, but noticable.

*How it normally looks*

[image]

*How I prefer it to look*

[image]

My question is that, I think doing these small fixes manually is bad. So my question is

Should I avoid doing it? I mean is it "wrong"?

And if not, is there a more automatic solution to this?

(Right now I am merely putting in some space after the roots. like `\,` )

Here is a smaller MWE, I think the right side looks better than the left.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \mathrm{d}x \qquad & \text{versus} \qquad \int \frac{\,1+x^2\,}{\,1+x^4\,}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{-1+\sqrt[n]{x}}} \qquad  & \text{versus} \qquad \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\,x\sqrt{-1+\sqrt[n]{x}\,}\,} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The pictures can still be simplified in order to focus on the target.

Comment: Could you drop the source somewhere?  It would help me understand the difference.

Comment: I can't perceive of any difference in the fractions in for instance #1 or #10

Comment: Yes, and there is a mistake in the copy of #11.  The source would help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could renew the `\sqrt` command to put the space in automatically.

Renewing the `\sqrt` command is a little tricky because it takes an optional argument. Luckily it has been demonstrated in

["Closed" (square) root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29834/closed-square-root-symbol)

Here's a screenshot of the result

[image]

In the MWE below, you'll see that I have `\renewcommand`ed the `\sqrt` command to be itself, but with a space immediately following it using `\,` The subtleties involved are described in detail in the linked post.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][]{\oldsqrt[#1]{#2}\,}


\begin{document}
OLD
\[
   \int\oldsqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x
\]  

NEW
\[
   \int\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x
\]  
\end{document}
```

I think that in the context of your particular document, you might want the option to define a separate 'spaced square root symbol' so that you don't affect all of the `\sqrt`. You could achieve this using

```
\newcommand{\ssqrt}[2][]{\oldsqrt[#1]{#2}\,}
```

and, of course, you can name it anything you like- I used `\ssqrt` to stand for 'spaced square root'.

Comment: Would it perhaps be better to use `\mathhop` so one would always get propper spacing ? =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar that should be taken care of via the `\LetLtxMacro` command- it's just the old `sqrt` but with a bit of space after it :)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar glad it helped- good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 6):

The issue of inserting a bit of space every time the "differential operator" `d` is used is best addressed by defining a new operator, say `\dee`, that leaves the required amount of whitespace before the operator *and* typesets the operator in upright ("roman") font. For instance, you could define

```
\newcommand{\dee}{\operatorname{d}\!}
```

in the preamble, and then use it from now on every time you are referring to a `d` that's a differential.

If you have no need for the Icelandic-d that's generated by LaTeX with the command `\d`, you could alternatively define, i.e., if you'd like to type `\d` to generate the differential operator "d", you could use the following definition:

```
\renewcommand{\d}{\operatorname{d}\!}
```

As @JimHefferon has pointed out in a comment, a slight spacing adjustment is required for typesetting inline math expressions such as `dy/dx` (with both `d`s set in upright mode). For this particular term, one would write (using the second definition above):

```
$\d y/\!\d x$
```

[image]

where the instruction `\!` instructs TeX to insert a "negative thin space," thereby undoing the "positive thin space" that's inserted by the operator `\d`.

Comment: Doesn't this look funny when you type $\dee y/\dee x$?

Comment: Personaly In my documents I simply type `\dy` and `\dx`, these are defined as `\mathrm{d}x \mathhop{}\ \!` =)

Comment: I'm sorry; so you have \def\dx{\mathrm{d}x \mathhop{}\ \!} is that right?  In particular, in the fraction $\dy/\dx$ you have the d's in mathrm but the x and y in italics?  When I tried it in the past, it looked odd to me.  (But my taste is not very well-developed, I admit.)

Comment: @JimHefferon: I've gone ahead and rewritten my answer to make use of the command `\operatorname`; the advantage of doing so, relative to the "brute force" definition, viz., `\renewcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}`, is that one avoids unnecessary whitespace if the operator is used at the beginning of a line (and at the start of some math material).

Comment: @JimHefferon : A quick note on style. It is not as much as if it looks good, but whetere it is "correct". Variables are in cursive, operators are not. ^^

Comment: For differential operators, derivatives, and so on, you might want to consider the `commath` package. I used to have a whole set of custom commands (like `\dy{y}{x}` for dy/dx, `\pa{f}{x}` for partial derivatives), but now I use this instead, which I find much cleaner.