# Nice-looking p-th roots

Tags: math-mode, symbols

When I take the `p`th root, the bottom of the `p` comes very close to the `\sqrt` symbol.  In the New Century Schoolbook font (which I am using), the `p` actually intersects the `\sqrt` symbol, which looks even more terrible.  Is there a clean way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the New Century Schoolbook font
\begin{document}
When I write $a^{(1/p)}$ as $\sqrt[p]{a}$, the bottom of the $p$
touches the top of the root symbol, which looks ugly.
Even when the root symbol is larger, such as with
$\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{n}}$, it still looks bad
(since the tail of the p almost hits that line).
\end{document}
```

[image: Ugly-looking <code>\sqrt[p]{a}</code>]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The amsmath package provides commands to tweak the position of the p, this example is from the amsmath documentation:

```
\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}\beta]{k}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is it wise to / how can I (re-)define the `\sqrt` command to use these preferences automatically?

Comment: @jamaicanworm you can redfine `\sqrt` using the method illustrated in [best-practices-for-spacing-regarding-fractions-and-roots/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48091/best-practices-for-spacing-regarding-fractions-and-roots/48095#48095) and the linked question within

Comment: This seems a bit simpler:  `\let\oldsqrt\sqrt  \def\sqrt[#1]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}#1]}`  Are there any disadvantages of this solution compared to the `LetLtxMacro` one you linked to?  Also, in this solution, there is a slight problem:  now, if I write `sqrt{a}` (without the optional `[]` argument), it gives an error.

Comment: don't use `\def` to define commands with optional arguments, use `\renewcommand\sqrt[2][2]{...` so the optional argument defaults to 2.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: As I told jamaicanworm already, it's always nice to have a picture of the result in an answer so that users can evaluate and compare answers without having to compile each one of them. Of course, you, too, will get more upvotes, which are the sole reason we're all here `:)`

Answer (score 30):

In line with the suggestion @DavidCarlisle gave in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49045/5001), I also recommend that you load the `amsmath` package and experiment a bit with the `\leftroot` and `\uproot` options to the `\sqrt` macro.

In fact, since your root symbol, `p`, has a longer lower-left spur and a smaller overall height than the `\beta` symbol that's used in the example code of the amsmath package's user guide does, you may want to use  `3` rather than `2` as the argument of both `\leftroot` and `\uproot` in order to get a more balanced looking expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % New Century Schoolbook text and math font clones
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt[p]{a}           & \sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}p]{a}    \\[2ex]
\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{n}} & \sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}p]{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24):

Quick and dirty answer:  use superscript p in the pth root symbol, i.e. \sqrt[^p]{x}.  Not elegant, but mostly good enough.  This is also fast and easy if you're using something like LyX.  For example:  [image]

Comment: What LyX shows in the editing window is only a weak approximation to the output in the final pdf document.

Comment: Pure filth. +1.

Answer (score 10):

This should be more of a comment (in reply to the OP's comment for David's answer) than answer (I can not break lines in comment).

You can define a new command `\mysqrt` instead of trying to meddle with the original `\sqrt` command.

```
\newcommand*{\mysqrt}[4]{\sqrt[\leftroot{#1}\uproot{#2}#3]{#4}}
\[\mysqrt{-2}{2}{\beta}{k}\]
\[\mysqrt{-3}{3}{\beta}{k}\]
\[\mysqrt{-2}{6}{\beta}{\frac{k}{h}}\]
```

**Advantage:** You can change the first two values values on the go and your old `\sqrt` works without the option `[]`.

[image]

Comment: Does `\mysqrt` work even if you omit one of those values (e.g., if you give it 1, 2, or 3 arguments instead of 4)?  Unfortunately, I already have a huge document full of `\sqrt`s, and I don't want to replace all of them.  But thanks for the help!

Comment: In this case I would make the first two parameters to `\mysqrt` optional and default to something that works for most cases, but can be tweaked if so desired.

Comment: @jamaicanworm If you do not give values TeX will complain of a `missing number` that will be treated as zero. Hence you can put zero yourself to avoid that complain. and yes it works except that complaint.

Comment: @PeterGrill How do you make a parameter optional?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Since there is more than one parameter that should be optional, I would use [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and the solutions described at [LaTeX command with optional arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48355/latex-command-with-optional-arguments)

Comment: @Peter Grill  I tried using the `xparse` package, but for some reason this is giving 82 errors:  `\let\oldsqrt\sqrt   \def\sqrt[#1]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}]\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}`

Comment: @jamaicanworm: That is not how to use `xparse`. Using `\NewDocumentCommand{\mysqrt}{O{-2} O{2} O{} m}{...}` will make `#1` default to `-2`, `#2` default to `2`, and `#3` default to `{}`. Hope that helps -- if not, this should really be a separate question as it might be useful to others as well.

Comment: Version discussed in the comments here is provided at [Optional arguments in \def](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49057/4301).

Answer (score 3):

I tried Unicode math Schola font (it is an equivalent to the New Century) and it seems that there is no problem when classical `\root` macro is used.
I did the test with OpTeX but you can try it with different macro if you want.

```
\fontfam[schola]

test: $\root p\of a$

\bye
```

[image: root of p]