# Optional arguments in \def

Tags: macros, symbols, optional-arguments

I want to re-define the `\sqrt` command (as detailed in [Nice-looking p-th roots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49043/9757)), and so far I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the New Century Schoolbook font
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
\def\sqrt[#1]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}#1]}

\begin{document}
This $\sqrt[p]{a}$ looks better than $\oldsqrt[p]{a}$,
since the $p$ does not intersect the root symbol.
\end{document}
```

However, when I try writing `\sqrt{a}`, I get an error.  How can I make the `#1` argument optional, so that if it is not passed in, it leaves that area above the root symbol blank (as it would in the default `\sqrt` command)?

(This is a follow-up to the comments on [David's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49045/9757) and [Harish's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49052/9757) to above-mentioned question.)

Comment: I would suggest using LaTeX's `\renewcommand` which handles optional arguments for you: `\renewcommand\sqrt[1][]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}#1]}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want commands with at most one optional argument, LaTeX's built in `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` are an easy way to define them. The syntax is

```
\(re)newcommand⟨\name⟩[⟨number of arguments⟩][⟨default value for the first argument⟩]{⟨code⟩]
```

If you specify the second optional argument, then the first argument to `\name` will be optional. So in your case one can simply use

```
\renewcommand\sqrt[1][]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}#1]}
```

Note that (as in your question), we do not need to specify the second argument, because `\oldsqrt` will look for it anyway, so that this definition is functionally equivalent to

```
\renewcommand\sqrt[2][]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}#1]{#2}}
```

If you need several optional arguments or an argument other than the first one should be optional, you can either chain `\@ifnextchar`s (as in Yiannis' answer), or use `xparse` (as in Peter's answer).

Comment: Thanks!  Just to be clear, you still need the line `\let\oldsqrt\sqrt` before the `\renewcommand`.

Answer (score 30):

The primitive `\def` does not understand optional arguments. That is provided in LaTeX only. What you have defined is a delimited argument:

```
  \def\sqrt[#1]{...}
```

which means that the input must always be provided as [...], you could have written anything instead of `[]`. To have an optional argument you need to define it in LaTeX using the following method:

```
  \DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[{true statement}{false statement}}
```

The `@\ifnextchar` checks to see if there is an `[` and branches accordingly. You will need to modify your script on this basis.

The commands are normally defined to call two macros, one delimited and another undelimited, as for example:

```
  \makeatletter
  \DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[{\@@sqrt}{\@sqrt}}
  \def\@@sqrt[#1]{I have a square bracket #1}  
  \def\@sqrt#1{I don't have a square bracket #1}
  \sqrt{1}
  \sqrt[3]
```

Now redefining `amsmath` macros, is like walking barefoot on a coal fire, so a few more items need to be taken care of. Firstly to let save the old command, we use Oberdiek's package `letltxmacro`

```
   \LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}
```

The rest are shown in the minimal below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the New Century Schoolbook font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[\@@sqrt\oldsqrt}
\newcommand\@@sqrt[2][]{\oldsqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}#1]{#2}}  
\[
   \sqrt{\alpha}\qquad
   \sqrt[\beta]{k} \qquad
   \sqrt[c]{k} \qquad
   \sqrt[d]{k}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't seem to work for me (it actually freezes `pdflatex`)... Maybe there is a problem because I need to use the `\sqrt` command where you wrote `I have a square bracket #1`, but I am simultaneously re-defining the `\sqrt` command?

Comment: @jamaicanworm It will freeze if you redefine it, as you will have infinite regression. Will post a full answer a bit later in the date.

Comment: @jamaicanworm Please see edit done after two caffeine injections:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides The `\ensuremath` in the definition of `\@@sqrt` you're using is wrong and not from a stylistic point of view. Also it's not clear why using `\DeclareRobustCommand` for `\@@sqrt`. Note also that redefining `\sqrt` in this way will prevent further usage of `\leftroot` and `\uproot`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Was sure I missed something and the reason I am normally reluctant to touch anything amsmath. I would appreciate it if you edit a correction in, otherwise will apply a correction in the evening. OP wanted to `fix` the parameters so I am not over worried about losing `\leftroot`

Comment: It is what I am looking for. (+100)

Answer (score 11):

### Using a new command: `\mysqrt`:

This is what I was suggesting in the comments to [Nice-looking p-th roots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49043/nice-looking-p-th-roots/49052#49052) using [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to make the first three parameters optional:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysqrt}{O{} O{-2} O{2}  m}{\sqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}}
```

Then `$\mysqrt[p]{a}$` would produce the desired result:

[image]

Note that the first optional parameter in the index of the `\sqrt`. The following two options are the tweaks that get applied to the `\leftroot` (defaults to `-2` in the above code) and the `\uproot` (defaults to `2`).

The same examples from the linked question would be specified as where the left uses the default settings and the right uses the manual tweaks:

```
\[\mysqrt[\beta]{k}            \quad\mysqrt[\beta][-3][3]{k}          \]
\[\mysqrt[\beta]{\frac{k}{h}}  \quad\mysqrt[\beta][-2][6]{\frac{k}{h}}\]
```

yielding:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mysqrt}{O{} O{-2} O{2}  m}{%
    \sqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}%
}%

\begin{document}\noindent
This $\mysqrt[p]{a}$ looks better than $\sqrt[p]{a}$,
since the $p$ does not intersect the root symbol.
\end{document}
```

---

### Redefine the existing `\sqrt` macro:

If you wish to redfine the `\sqrt` globally then you have to use `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package since `\sqrt` has optional parameters already.

### References:

- A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question on [closed square root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4301)

The following produces results identical to the second image above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldSqrt}{\sqrt}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\sqrt}{O{} O{-2} O{2}  m}{\OldSqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}}%

\begin{document}\noindent
\[\sqrt[\beta]{k}            \quad\sqrt[\beta][-3][3]{k}          \]
\[\sqrt[\beta]{\frac{k}{h}}  \quad\sqrt[\beta][-2][6]{\frac{k}{h}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The problem is that I already have a long document with many uses of `\sqrt`.  I want to re-define the `\sqrt` command at the top of the document, without having to find-and-replace each one with `\mysqrt`.

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Ok, have provided a solution for that as well.

Comment: Nice piece of work!

Answer (score 5):

This answer is about solving the *specific* problem, that is, initializing `\leftroot` and `\uproot` to different values from the default, leaving intact the possibility of using them for particular cases.

The trick is to notice that `amsmath` uses the values given as arguments to `\leftroot` and `\uproot` to set two count registers, `\leftroot@` and `\uproot@` which are initialized to zero. This happens in the internal macro called `\root`. Thus one can do

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\root}{\uproot@\z@}{\uproot@3 }{}{}
\patchcmd{\root}{\leftroot@\z@}{\leftroot@-3 }{}{}
\makeatother
```

and now those initial values will be applied, but saying

```
\sqrt[\leftroot{1}x]{y}
```

would give the same result as `\sqrt[\leftroot{1}\uproot{3}x]{y}` without the patching, which might be useful in particular cases. Similarly, `\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{0}x]{y}` would give the same result as the original `\sqrt[x]{y}`.

As Stefan Lehmke points out in his comment, changing the meaning of `\sqrt` is not really recommended. However, setting a different default for `\leftroot` and `\uproot` could be justified with some document fonts. The important thing is to know how the new `\sqrt` behaves with respect to `\leftroot` and `\uproot`.

Making `\leftroot` and `\uproot` adding to the default requires a very extensive patching of `\root`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\default@leftroot{-3} % set the default value of leftroot
\def\default@uproot{3}    % set the default value of uproot
\renewcommand{\root}{\relaxnext@
  \DN@{\ifx\@let@token\uproot\let\next@\nextii@\else
   \ifx\@let@token\leftroot\let\next@\nextiii@\else
   \let\next@\plainroot@\fi\fi\next@}%
  \def\nextii@\uproot##1{\uproot@\numexpr(\default@uproot+##1)\relax\FN@\nextiv@}%
  \def\nextiv@{\ifx\@let@token\@sptoken\DN@. {\FN@\nextv@}\else
   \DN@.{\FN@\nextv@}\fi\next@.}%
  \def\nextv@{\ifx\@let@token\leftroot\let\next@\nextvi@\else
   \let\next@\plainroot@\fi\next@}%
  \def\nextvi@\leftroot##1{\leftroot@\numexpr(\default@leftroot+##1)\relax\plainroot@}%
   \def\nextiii@\leftroot##1{\leftroot@\numexpr(\default@leftroot+##1)\relax\FN@\nextvii@}%
  \def\nextvii@{\ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
   \DN@. {\FN@\nextviii@}\else
   \DN@.{\FN@\nextviii@}\fi\next@.}%
  \def\nextviii@{\ifx\@let@token\uproot\let\next@\nextix@\else
   \let\next@\plainroot@\fi\next@}%
  \def\nextix@\uproot##1{\uproot@\numexpr(\default@uproot+##1)\relax\plainroot@}%
  \bgroup\uproot@\default@uproot \leftroot@\default@leftroot\relax \FN@\next@}
\makeatother
```

(Thanks to Stefan Lehmke for spotting an error in the initial version.)

Comment: Here's a slightly less invasive patch:
`\def\mynextvi@root\leftroot#1{\advance\leftroot@#1\relax\plainroot@}%
\def\mynextiii@root\leftroot#1{\advance\leftroot@#1\relax\FN@\nextvii@}%
\def\mynextii@root\uproot#1{\advance\uproot@#1\relax\FN@\nextiv@}%
\patchcmd{\root}{\uproot@\z@}{\uproot@3 }{}{}
\patchcmd{\root}{\leftroot@\z@}{\leftroot@-10\let\nextii@\mynextii@root\let\nextiii@\mynextiii@root\let\nextvi@\mynextvi@root}{}{}
`
But that's a matter of taste I assume. 
While you're at it, you could consider putting the defaults into global registers...
Darn, no newlines in comments...

Comment: Parametrizing the defaults was indeed the next step (I thought to it just after closing the edit, but I had to go and catch the train).

Comment: Thanks!  In your patch, why are `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` necessary?

Comment: @jamaicanworm Those are necessary because we are using commands with `@` in their names.