# Adding white space under a letter or symbol

Tags: math-mode, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nice-looking p-th roots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49043/nice-looking-p-th-roots)

There is symbol overlap in `$\sqrt[a_1]{x}$`. Is there a way to increase the vertical position of `$a_1$`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[a_{1}]{x}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try: `$\sqrt[\raisebox{\depth}{$\scriptstyle a_{1}$}]{x}$.`

Comment: Using the `\raisebox` command, for example: `$\sqrt[\raisebox{4pt}{{\scriptsize$a_1$}}]{x}$`. See the help for the command: [raisebox  help](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/latex-help/ltx-157.html).

Answer (score 8):

if you're using the `amsmath` package, you can use `\uproot`:

```
$\sqrt[\uproot{2} {a_{1}}]{x}$.
```

some experimentation may be required to determine the best spacing.

there's also `\leftroot` to shift the index horizontally.

both `\uproot` and `\leftroot` will accept a negative value to shift the index in the opposite direction.

by the way, this has been addressed before, in
[using-leftroot-uproot-with-closed-square-root-symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49064) and [nice-looking-p-th-roots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49043).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an option, in the form of a new command `\Sqrt[<index>][<raise>]{<root>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\Sqrt}{O{} O{0pt} m}{%
  \sqrt[\raisebox{#2}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}]{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[a_{1}]{x}$. $\Sqrt[a_{1}]{x}$. 
$\Sqrt[a_{1}][1pt]{x}$. $\Sqrt[a_{1}][2pt]{x}$.
\end{document}
```

It may be futile though to introduce a new command for a very small case. On a side note, using subscripts in `\scriptscriptstyle` (the font size used to indicate the root index), doesn't translate very well (note the similarly-sized `1` compared to `a`).

Comment: Excelent answer!.