# size and location of cube root symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, positioning, displaystyle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nice-looking p-th roots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49043/nice-looking-p-th-roots)

On math.stackexchange I wanted the cube root of a fraction in display mode, and used  `$$\sqrt[3]{\frac ab}$$` to get it.  The 3 comes out very small and low in the root sign.  I also thought of `$$^3\sqrt{\frac ab}$$` but the 3 comes out too far to the left.

Comment: @PeterGrill:  Thanks.  I searched for a while to try to find something like that, but didn't.

Comment: Yeah, things are not always easy to find here. I only knew it exited as I had asked a follow up question: [Using \leftroot{}, \uproot{} with closed square root symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49064/using-leftroot-uproot-with-closed-square-root-symbol) where I had referenced that question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `\leftroot` (for horizontal shifting), and/or `\uproot` (for vertical shifting) from the `amsmath` package; using `\scriptstyle` you can increase the size of the index (not sure if this is a good idea); preferable to use a superscript instead of the root:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}\qquad \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{\frac{a}{b}}\qquad
\Bigl(\frac{a}{b}\Bigr)^{1/3} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]