# Enable \ifmeasuring@ flag

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, boxes

Apparently the `\DHLhksqrt` macro in the MWE below measures its content 20 times:

[image]

### Questions:

1. Where exactly can I put the `\measuring@true` and `\measuring@false` so that I get the count of 1?  If you uncomment the `\measuring` lines the count drops to 16 so then 4 measurements are taking place between the two commented lines.
2. *Bonus:* Where are the 20 measurements coming from?

### Reference:

- [Using \leftroot{}, \uproot{} with closed square root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49064/using-leftroot-uproot-with-closed-square-root-symbol)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ClosedSqrt}[1][]{\def\DHLindex{#1}\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}%
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
  %\measuring@true
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0\relax%
  \advance\dimen0-0.25\ht0\relax%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\kern-0.375pt\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
  %\measuring@false
  {%
    \hbox{$#1\expandafter\oldsqrt\expandafter[\DHLindex]{#2\,}$}%
    \lower\ifx\math@version\bold@name0.60pt\else0.4pt\fi\box2%
  }%
}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sqrt}{O{\hphantom{3}} O{0} O{0}  m}{\ClosedSqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}}%

\newcounter{NumberOfInstances}
\setcounter{NumberOfInstances}{0}
\newcommand*{\MyValue}{%
    \ifmeasuring@\else%
        \stepcounter{NumberOfInstances}%
    \fi
    x%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\[ \sqrt{\MyValue} \]      
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you can get it smaller than 4 because og the mathpalette, don't it have to run it in all four modes before deciding which one to use?

Comment: @daleif: But `$\frac{\MyValue}{1}$` does not have such a problem. Doesn't `\frac{}{}` goes through a similar process to decide how the fraction should be typeset?

Comment: Not sure, you'd probably need egreg to explain it.

Comment: I don't think amsmath's `\measuring@` is thought out to be set. And anyhow if I do not load `mathtools` at all comment out the `\leftroot`, `\uproot`, and `\ifmeasuring@` things, I again get `20` with your code.

Comment: Every `\mathchoice` command (called by `\mathpalette`) typesets four boxes. Five calls of `\mathchoice` make for twenty boxes; the original `\sqrt` command (when the optional argument is used) calls `\mathpalette` and so does `\phantom` in math mode.

Comment: And you can't turn off the measuring, of course, because it must be different for each of the four boxes.

Comment: @jfbu: Yes, `\measuring@` is not set. I want to be able to set it so that I can disable the counting during that phase.

Comment: @egreg: Don't want to turn off measuring, just want to know when measuring is taking place so that I count it just once. One solution might be to typeset the parameter into a `\savebox` first.

Comment: This is purely academic, isn't it? Or do you ***really*** want to use the abominable closed square root sign?

Comment: May be you can use [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274912/21930) to get something half- expandable (altough I don't really know if it does work always). Or use the `mathstyle` package to get an expandable `\mathchoice`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem when text is processed multiple times and this of course happens when `\mathpalette` is involved.

If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{noi}
\newcommand{\doit}{\stepcounter{noi}x}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[3]{\doit}$
Number of instances: \thenoi 
\end{document}
```

(note the optional argument) you get 4 as the number of instances. You'd get just 1 with `\sqrt{\doit}`.

In the case of the closed square root symbol, the optional argument is *always* assumed, so the routine is called four times because `\mathpalette` enters into action.

You can greatly reduce the amount of stepping by loading `amsmath` (well, `amstext`) and redefining `\mathpalette` to set `\iffirstchoice@`. The package redefines `\stepcounter` and `\addtocounter` to do nothing when `\iffirstchoice@` returns false. This is used in `\text` for avoiding to step counters four times. However, `\mathpalette` is not redefined, so we need to. Also, `\firstchoice@false` must be issued when the argument possibly containing counter stepping is subject to trial typesetting.

Note that this just turns off excess stepping, not the number of times the boxes are typeset (which is indeed 20).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\def\mathpalette#1#2{%
  \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle{#2}}%
    {\firstchoice@false#1\textstyle{#2}}%
    {\firstchoice@false#1\scriptstyle{#2}}%
    {\firstchoice@false#1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}}
\makeatother

\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ClosedSqrt}[1][]{\def\DHLindex{#1}\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}%
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
  \sbox0{\firstchoice@false$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0\relax
  \advance\dimen0-0.25\ht0\relax
  \sbox2{\kern-0.375pt\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
  {%
    \hbox{$#1\expandafter\oldsqrt\expandafter[\DHLindex]{#2\,}$}%
    \lower\ifx\math@version\bold@name0.60pt\else0.4pt\fi\box2
  }%
}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sqrt}{O{\hphantom{3}} O{0} O{0}  m}{\ClosedSqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}}%

\newcounter{NumberOfInstances}
\setcounter{NumberOfInstances}{0}
\newcommand*{\MyValue}{%
        \stepcounter{NumberOfInstances}%
    x%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\[ \sqrt{\MyValue} \]      
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\[ \oldsqrt[3]{\MyValue} \]      
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For reducing the stepping to one, you need to also modify the definition of `\r@@t`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\def\mathpalette#1#2{%
  \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle{#2}}%
    {\firstchoice@false#1\textstyle{#2}}%
    {\firstchoice@false#1\scriptstyle{#2}}%
    {\firstchoice@false#1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}}
\def\r@@t#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\else\firstchoice@false\fi
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sqrtsign{#2}$}%
  \dimen@\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@-\dp\z@
  \mkern5mu\raise.6\dimen@\copy\rootbox
  \mkern-10mu\box\z@}
\makeatother

\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ClosedSqrt}[1][]{\def\DHLindex{#1}\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}%
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
  \sbox4{\firstchoice@false$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht4\relax
  \advance\dimen0-0.25\ht0\relax
  \sbox2{\kern-0.375pt\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
  {%
    \hbox{$#1\expandafter\oldsqrt\expandafter[\DHLindex]{#2\,}$}%
    \lower\ifx\math@version\bold@name0.60pt\else0.4pt\fi\box2
  }%
}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sqrt}{O{\hphantom{3}} O{0} O{0}  m}{\ClosedSqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}}%

\newcounter{NumberOfInstances}
\setcounter{NumberOfInstances}{0}
\newcommand*{\MyValue}{%
        \stepcounter{NumberOfInstances}%
    x%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\[ \sqrt{\MyValue} \]      
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\[ \oldsqrt[3]{\MyValue} \]      
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps you could make more explicit that the effect of `\firstchoice@false` is to suppress the `\stepcounter/\addtocounter` action, that there continues to be the four-fold mathpalette typesetting ? I am not sure but I gather the OP was using `\MyValue` to count the typesetting phases, maybe I do not quite get what he is aiming at. (in other terms the 20 is still there, but now hidden if the thermometer has been suppressed via `\firstchoice@false`)

Comment: @jfbu Unfortunately today's train was on schedule, so I hadn't the usual additional time for polishing my answer.

Comment: So it is safe to redefine `\mathpalette`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I see no problem, provided `amstext` is loaded (via `amsmath`, usually).

Answer (score 2):

A more detailed count. Done without amsmath for clarification, as `\ifmeasuring@` is only for querying and setting it can have no effect except surprises.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ClosedSqrt}[1][]{\def\DHLindex{#1}\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}%
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
  %\measuring@true
\typeout{Processing DHLhksqrt (#1, start): \the\value{NumberOfInstances}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0\relax%
\typeout{Processing DHLhksqrt (#1, after first oldsqrt): \the\value{NumberOfInstances}}%
  \advance\dimen0-0.25\ht0\relax%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\kern-0.375pt\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
  %\measuring@false
  {%
    \hbox{$#1\expandafter\oldsqrt\expandafter[\DHLindex]{#2\,}$}%
    \lower\ifx\math@version\bold@name0.60pt\else0.4pt\fi\box2%
  }%
\typeout{Processing DHLhksqrt (#1, after second oldsqrt): \the\value{NumberOfInstances}}%
}%


%\RenewDocumentCommand{\sqrt}{O{\hphantom{3}} O{0} O{0}  m}{\ClosedSqrt[\leftroot{#2}\uproot{#3}#1]{#4}}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sqrt}{O{\hphantom{3}} O{0} O{0}  m}{\ClosedSqrt[#2#3#1]{#4}}%

\newcounter{NumberOfInstances}
\setcounter{NumberOfInstances}{0}
\newcommand*{\MyValue}{%
%    \ifmeasuring@%\else%
        \stepcounter{NumberOfInstances}%
%    \fi
    x%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\[ \sqrt{\MyValue} \]      
NumberOfInstances=\arabic{NumberOfInstances}.
\end{document}
```

Here is the log:

```
Processing DHLhksqrt (\displaystyle , start): 0
Processing DHLhksqrt (\displaystyle , after first oldsqrt): 1
Processing DHLhksqrt (\displaystyle , after second oldsqrt): 5
Processing DHLhksqrt (\textstyle , start): 5
Processing DHLhksqrt (\textstyle , after first oldsqrt): 6
Processing DHLhksqrt (\textstyle , after second oldsqrt): 10
Processing DHLhksqrt (\scriptstyle , start): 10
Processing DHLhksqrt (\scriptstyle , after first oldsqrt): 11
Processing DHLhksqrt (\scriptstyle , after second oldsqrt): 15
Processing DHLhksqrt (\scriptscriptstyle , start): 15
Processing DHLhksqrt (\scriptscriptstyle , after first oldsqrt): 16
Processing DHLhksqrt (\scriptscriptstyle , after second oldsqrt): 20
```

Conclusion: using `\sqrt` with optional argument causes `4` passes. And `20 = 4x(1+4)`.

Comment: in the last sentence `\sqrt` refers naturally to original `\sqrt`.