# Shift points with error bars pstricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I need to shift the data points in a pstricks plot with error bars slightly to improve readability. The points lay on each other and can not be good differenciated. I tried to modifiy the `\def`fed commands, but without succes. 
Best would be to have a optional or second argument to the `\GetCoordinates` command to add a shift at the x-Axis.

Here is a MWE with the data (1 and 2) and how it should look like (3 and 4):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data1.txt}
    5 7.346642472 0.570377917 -0.5703779173
    5.5 7.568566113 0.575130876 -0.5751308769
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data2.txt}
    5 7.042472165 0.370377917 -0.370377917
    5.5 7.925676113 0.325130876 -0.325130876
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data3.txt}
    6.075 7.346642472 0.570377917 -0.5703779173
    6.5075 7.568566113 0.575130876 -0.5751308769
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data4.txt}
    5.925 7.042472165 0.370377917 -0.370377917
    6.425 7.925676113 0.325130876 -0.325130876
\end{filecontents*}
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-bar,pst-fill}


\SpecialCoor
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pst-node}
\makeatletter
\SpecialCoor
\def\errorLine{\@ifnextchar[{\pst@errorLine}{\pst@errorLine[]}}
\def\pst@errorLine[#1](#2)#3#4{{%
        \ifx#1\empty\else\psset{#1}\fi
        \pst@getcoor{#2}\pst@tempb
        \def\@errorMin{#3}
        \def\@errorMax{#4}
        \psline{|*-|*}%
        (!%
        /yDot \pst@tempb exch pop \pst@number\psyunit div def
        /xDot \pst@tempb pop \pst@number\psxunit div def
        xDot yDot \@errorMin\space add%
        )(!%
        /yDot \pst@tempb exch pop \pst@number\psyunit div def
        /xDot \pst@tempb pop \pst@number\psxunit div def
        xDot yDot \@errorMax\space add%
        )
}}
%
\def\GetCoordinates#1{\expandafter\GetCoordinates@i#1}
\def\GetCoordinates@i #1{\GetCoordinates@ii#1}
\def\GetCoordinates@ii#1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 {%
    \DoCoordinate{#2}{#4}%
    \errorLine[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.8pt,tbarsize=2pt 4](#2,#4){#6}{#8}% <<<<<
    \@ifnextchar D{\GetCoordinates@ii}{}}
\makeatother
\def\DoCoordinate#1#2{\psdot(#1,#2)}



\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=0.2}
\begin{pspicture}(4.5,0)(9.5,42)
\psaxes[Ox=40,Dx=10,dx=1,Oy=0,Dy=500,dy=5,%
ysubticks=2,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,ticksize=6pt,tickwidth=0.8pt]{->}(4,0)(9.5,42)

%Bad ones
\readdata{\OHrot}{Data1.txt}
\readdata{\Nrot}{Data2.txt}
\psset{linecolor=DarkSeaGreen3}
\GetCoordinates{\OHrot}
\psset{linecolor=LightBlue3}
\GetCoordinates{\Nrot}

% Shifted ones
\readdata{\OHrot}{Data3.txt}
\readdata{\Nrot}{Data4.txt}
\psset{linecolor=DarkSeaGreen3}
\GetCoordinates{\OHrot}
\psset{linecolor=LightBlue3}
\GetCoordinates{\Nrot}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data1.txt}
    5 7.346642472 0.570377917 -0.5703779173
    5.5 7.568566113 0.575130876 -0.5751308769
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data2.txt}
    5 7.042472165 0.370377917 -0.370377917
    5.5 7.925676113 0.325130876 -0.325130876
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data3.txt}
    6.075 7.346642472 0.570377917 -0.5703779173
    6.5075 7.568566113 0.575130876 -0.5751308769
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Data4.txt}
    5.925 7.042472165 0.370377917 -0.370377917
    6.425 7.925676113 0.325130876 -0.325130876
\end{filecontents*}
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-bar,pst-fill}


\SpecialCoor
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pst-node}
\makeatletter
\SpecialCoor
\def\errorLine{\@ifnextchar[{\pst@errorLine}{\pst@errorLine[]}}
\def\pst@errorLine[#1](#2)#3#4{{%
        \ifx#1\empty\else\psset{#1}\fi
        \pst@getcoor{#2}\pst@tempb
        \def\@errorMin{#3}
        \def\@errorMax{#4}
        \psline{|*-|*}%
        (!%
        /yDot \pst@tempb exch pop \pst@number\psyunit div def
        /xDot \pst@tempb pop \pst@number\psxunit div \XShift\space sub def
        xDot yDot \@errorMin\space add%
        )(!%
        /yDot \pst@tempb exch pop \pst@number\psyunit div def
        /xDot \pst@tempb pop \pst@number\psxunit div  \XShift\space sub def
        xDot yDot \@errorMax\space add%
        )
}}
%
\def\GetCoordinates[#1]#2{\def\XShift{#1}\expandafter\GetCoordinates@i#2}
\def\GetCoordinates@i #1{\GetCoordinates@ii#1}
\def\GetCoordinates@ii#1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 {%
    \DoCoordinate{#2}{#4}%
    \errorLine[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.8pt,tbarsize=2pt 4](#2,#4){#6}{#8}% <<<<<
    \@ifnextchar D{\GetCoordinates@ii}{}}
\makeatother
\def\DoCoordinate#1#2{\psdot(!#1 \XShift\space sub #2)}



\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=0.2}
\begin{pspicture}(4.5,0)(9.5,42)
\psaxes[Ox=40,Dx=10,dx=1,Oy=0,Dy=500,dy=5,%
ysubticks=2,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,ticksize=6pt,tickwidth=0.8pt]{->}(4,0)(9.5,42)

%Bad ones
\readdata{\OHrot}{Data1.txt}
\readdata{\Nrot}{Data2.txt}
\psset{linecolor=DarkSeaGreen3}%
\GetCoordinates[0.1]{\OHrot}

\psset{linecolor=LightBlue3}%
\GetCoordinates[-0.1]{\Nrot}
%
% Shifted ones
\readdata{\OHrot}{Data3.txt}
\readdata{\Nrot}{Data4.txt}
\psset{linecolor=DarkSeaGreen3}%
\GetCoordinates[0.1]{\OHrot}
\psset{linecolor=LightBlue3}%
\GetCoordinates[-0.1]{\Nrot}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I modified your solution after https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49056/63420 and added another main command like this: `\DeclareRobustCommand\GetCoordinates{\@ifnextchar[{\@@GetCoordinates}{\@GetCoordinates}}`. One with the old command, the other with your command, which works fine.