# Replace part number by an acronym

Tags: chapters, parts, scrbook, scrartcl

I would like to replace a part number by an abbreviation. For exemple, concerning the part algebra of the following MWE, I would like that the first chapter be called `ALG.1` instead of `I.1` (and the same for all the chapters in the considered part).

The abbreviation `ALG` could be ideally an optional argument of the `\part` command.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

%reset chapter for each part
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}


\begin{document}

\part{Algebra} %\part[ALG]{Algebra} ?
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Analysis}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Geometry}
\chapter{Chap 1}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, with an `\acropart` command to be used just after the `\part` command:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\acropart[1]{\gdef\@acropart{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\@acropart.~\arabic{chapter}}
\makeatother

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Algebra} %\part[ALG]{Algebra} ?
\acropart{ALG}
\chapter{Chapter the first}
\chapter{Chapter the second}

\part{Analysis}
\acropart{ANAL}
\chapter{Chapter the first}

\part{Geometry}
\acropart{GEOM}
\chapter{Chapter the first}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The MWE in the question already contains a redefinition of `\thechapter`. This can be customized further by replacing the part counter `\thepart` with a new macro that contains the required abbreviation.

To set this using an optional argument to `\part` the old definition of `\part` can be stored in another macro such as `\oldpart`, and then `\part` can be redefined to accept an optional argument, store that in a macro, and then call the `\oldpart` macro which will process the default argument, similar to [Optional arguments in \def](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49056/optional-arguments-in-def). The default value of the optional argument is `\thepart`, to allow parts without a label to be numbered with the roman part number.

When a Table of Contents is printed the chapter labels do not fit the default width, this can be addressed using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=1.5cm
]{chapter}

\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand\part[1][\thepart]{\def\partacr{#1}\oldpart}
%reset chapter for each part
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\partacr.\arabic{chapter}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part[ALG]{Algebra}
\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}

\part{Geometry}
\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

%reset chapter for each part
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\prt}[2]{\part{#2}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{#1\arabic{chapter}}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{1.2cm} %<-- For tableofcontents 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\prt{ALG}{Algebra} %\part[ALG]{Algebra} ?
\chapter{Chap 1}

\prt{ANA}{Analysis}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\prt{GEO}{Geometry}
\chapter{Chap 1}


\end{document}
```

[image]