# Sqrt with fraction in root argument

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nice-looking p-th roots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49043/nice-looking-p-th-roots)

How can I move the root higher for this formula ? The fraction in the root is typeset to low:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

$\sqrt[\frac{1}{3}]{\frac{4}{4.2}}$

\end{document}
```

the result of the document is

[image: root 1/3 is typeset to low]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{5}\frac{1}{3}]{\frac{4}{4.2}}$

\end{document}
```

Unit for the macros is mu (mathunit 1mu=1/18em)

[image]

See also page 59 of mathmode document -> `texdoc mathmode`

Comment: It is better. I have other question: how do the commands

    \leftroot

and

    \uproot


work? Is there any formula to calculate their arguments, depends on the fraction?

Comment: the insert only vertical and/or horizontal space which doesn't depend to the following argument