# Table of Contents page numbers to first page of chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm creating a document based on the Memoir class. My chapter titles have a custom style so that the chapter number and title are on one page, but the text begins on the next page. I would like the ToC entry to reference the first page of the chapter.

Here's a correct MWE with the ToC for Chapter 1 referencing page 2, using a manual page break after the chapter [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86640/how-can-i-add-a-page-break-after-a-chapter-title).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{customchapterstyle}{
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\vspace*{\fill}\par\pagebreak}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\chapterstyle{customchapterstyle}
\chapter{Foo}
\vspace*{\fill}\par\pagebreak   % Manual page break
This is some text.
\end{document}
```

But I would prefer putting it in the style and so it doesn't have to be done in every chapter. If I put the `\pagebreak` code in the `\afterchaptertitle` command and use `\chapterstyle` rather than the manual page break, the ToC entry says page 3 instead of 2. How can I modify the chapter style so that the entry in the ToC entry points to the chapter title page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `\mempostaddchaptertotochook` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{customchapterstyle}{
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand{\mempostaddchaptertotochook}{\vspace*{\fill}\par\pagebreak}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapterstyle{customchapterstyle}
\chapter{Foo}
This is some text.

\end{document}
```