# Redefine macro in terms of old one

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself)

How can I redefine the same macro that uses the original macro?

```
\newcommand{\macro}{zzz}
\renewcommand{\macro}{xyz\macro}
```

(this results in an endless loop)

calling `\macro` should print xyzzzz. (I want to redefine some symbols)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the macros don't have optional parameters you can use:

```
\newcommand{\macro}{zzz}
\let\OldMacro\macro
\renewcommand{\macro}{xyz\OldMacro}
```

If you wish to redefine a macro that has optional parameters, you have to use `\LetLtxMacro` from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) . A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question at [closed square root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4301).

The MWE below yields:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\macro}{zzz}
\let\OldMacro\macro
\renewcommand{\macro}{xyz\OldMacro}

\begin{document}
\verb|\OldMacro:| \OldMacro

\verb|\macro:| \macro
\end{document}
```