# Redefine \LaTeX command for referring to a glossary entry

Tags: macros, pdftex, glossaries

I am writing on a quite large document and decided to put `\LaTeX{}` into my glossary

```
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name={\protect\LaTeX}, 
    description={blabla},
    sort={latex}
}
```

To link every `\LaTeX{}` to the glossary, I could replace everytime I used the macro in the text with `\gls{latex}` but I found it more convenient redefining `\LaTeX{}`. Unfortunately, it does not work. When I use

```
\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}
```

Nothing happen. When I use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}
```

I got `!TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`
So I thought, I may need to avoid `\LaTeX` inside the glossary itself and added

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\origLaTeX}{\LaTeX}
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name={\protect\origLaTeX}, 
    description={blabla},
    sort={latex}
}
```

But I still got the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\XC@edef #1#2->\begingroup
\ifnum \catcode `\!=13 \edef !{\string !}\fi \ifn...
l.1 ...some text with \LaTeX macro in it
```

Comment: Not that it is important, but for me `\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}` also errors in a small example (https://gist.github.com/moewew/30646181ab021d6c4fdbe00e0a6d4d2c). The problem here and with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}` is that you essentially end up defining `\LaTeX` as calling `\LaTeX` again (`\gls{latex}` ends up calling `\protect\LaTeX`) and so you get this infinite loop. With `\DeclareRobustCommand{\origLaTeX}{\LaTeX}` you cannot avoid the loop, since now `\gls{latex}` calls `\protect\origLaTeX`, which is `\LaTeX`, so you again have `\LaTeX` calling itself.

Comment: You could use the new `\NewCommandCopy` to really copy the definition of `\LaTeX` to `\origLaTeX`: https://gist.github.com/moewew/b02f533a51131ee10beba9de3aaaefcf. But I don't think this is a particularly good idea. I'd probably just stick with using `\gls{latex}` or at least use a macro name for it that isn't already taken.

Comment: @moewe Of course, I understand that. However, from a discussion like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51401/redefine-macro-in-terms-of-old-one, I got the impression that defining an intermediate macro like `\origLaTeX` would fix the issue. But it doesnt. I also tried the version `\let\origLaTeX\LaTeX` as suggested in that question but it didn't help either.

Comment: @moewe Can you elaborate a little why using `\NewCommandCopy` is not a "particularly good idea"?

Comment: Yes, an intermediate macro does help, but it depends how it is defined. With `\newcommand*{\origLaTeX}{\LaTeX}` you just have `\origLaTeX` expand to `\LaTeX`, which still gives you infinite recursion. But with `\let\x\y` the definition of `\y` is copied into `\x`, so `\x` does not expand to `\y` it expands to `\y`'s definition/expansion. The problem here is that `\LaTeX` is a robust macro, which is defined internally via a helper macro, and so it cannot be `\let` around 'just like that'. That's what `\NewCommandCopy` takes care of. ...

Comment: ... I don't think there is a TeXnical reason why using `\NewCommandCopy` is not a particularly good idea here, it's just that you redefine the definition of a "standard macro" to do something different. That can have unintended consequences when code you don't have control over uses that macro. Granted, for `\LaTeX` that probably is not much of a concern. But in general redefining core macros in a way that makes them do a whole lot more than before can be dangerous. (I have to go now, but if you like I can write an answer up later. In case no one else does.)

Comment: I was going to say that I would accept this an answer to my question if you actually make at one :) Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we define

```
\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}
```

we tell TeX that the macro `\LaTeX` should expand to `\gls{latex}`. So whenever TeX encounters `\LaTeX`, it will just try to use `\gls{latex}` instead.

Thanks to

```
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name={\protect\LaTeX}, 
    description={blabla},
    sort={latex}
}
```

`\gls{latex}` will end up printing `\protect\LaTeX` in many cases (amongst other things; the command does more). But now LaTeX sees the `\LaTeX` in `\protect\LaTeX`, expands it and sees that it expands to `\gls{latex}`. This results in the infinite loop you get.

The result is pretty much the same with

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}
```

Here LaTeX doesn't define `\LaTeX` to be `\gls{latex}` directly. Instead it defines `\LaTeX` via an auxiliary macro that then expands to `\gls{latex}`. This just adds one further layer to our infinite loop, but does not change the end result.

---

We could avoid the issue if could *copy* the actual definition of `\LaTeX` and give it a different name. Then we could overwrite `\LaTeX` and define it in terms of our copy of `\LaTeX`. That way we get out of the infinite loop because no macro tries to expand itself.

That is the approach with `\let\origLaTeX\LaTeX`. Unfortunately, this does not work since `\LaTeX` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}`, which – as alluded to above – does not actually define `\LaTeX` directly, it defines it via a helper macro, which contains the actual definition. When we do `\let\origLaTeX\LaTeX`, TeX copies the definition of `\LaTeX` into `\origLaTeX`. But the helper macro that actually contains the definition of `\LaTeX` is not copied over or changed. Since we defined our new version of `\LaTeX` also with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}`, `\origLaTeX` actually ends up calling `\gls{latex}` via the helper again.

Long story short, you cannot properly use `\let` with macros defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`<sup>Sometimes people get lucky and things appear to work, but this is not something you can rely on.</sup>. That's why the package `letltxmacro` was written. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/35864. With a current version of LaTeX, you won't need an extra package, you can use `\NewCommandCopy` to actually copy macro definitions without having to worry if the macro was defined with `\newcommand` or `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Hence

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
  name={\protect\origLaTeX}, 
  description={blabla},
  sort={latex}
}

\makeglossaries

\NewCommandCopy\origLaTeX\LaTeX
\renewcommand*{\LaTeX}{\gls{latex}}

\begin{document}
\LaTeX

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

works as desired and produces

[image: LaTeX logo in text and "LaTeX blabla. 1" in glossary.]

---

As I said in the comments I don't think there is a TeXnical reason why using `\NewCommandCopy` is not a particularly good idea here: It's just we'd change the definition of a LaTeX core macro to do something very different from its original definition. That can have unintended consequences when code you don't have control over uses that macro. Granted, for `\LaTeX` that probably is not much of a concern. But in general redefining core macros in a way that makes them do a whole lot more than before can be dangerous.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! One minor comment. After `\begin{document}` should be `\LaTeX` rather than `\gls{latex}` because that was the whole point of it :)

Comment: @Highchiller Oops. Thanks for catching that. Fixed.