# "Automatic" section labeling?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, memoir, links

I would like to be able to link within a document to another section without having to explicitly put a label after that other section command. `hyperref` does this with the TOC labels, so I think that this isn't an insane desire or anything. I've got a very large document that I'm converting to LaTeX (1100 pages) and much of the conversion has been automated in terms of `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` declarations. But I also need to be able to link to other sections based on their name.

As an example, the text (a game's rulebook) will refer to rules written in another section such as:

> Creatures immune to acid's caustic properties might still drown in it if they are 
>   totally immersed (see Drowning).

and then "(see Drowning)" should have the word Drowning be a link to the section (or subsection) titled Drowning.

It's not always clear which other parts will be sections or subsections as I'm going through and adding links (because of the size of the work, I can't remember all of it all the time), so I'd like sections, subsections, and subsubsections to all have the same "prefix" on their label, 'sec:'

Right now I have a command

```
\newcommand{\skillentry}[2]{\subsection[#1]{#1 #2}\index{#1}\label{skill:#1}}
```

and then an associated command

```
\newcommand{\linkskill}[1]{\hyperref[skill:#1]{#1}}
```

Given that no two sections, subsections, or subsubsections will ever have duplicate names, and also that a whole lot of the document is already written so that I don't want to just use a custom command, It *seems like* the logical solution would be to redefine `\@makesectionhead` so that it includes

```
\label{sec:#1}
```

inside the `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` command definitions (with `#1` here being the name of the section to be created), and a custom shortcut command such as:

```
\newcommand{\linksec}[1]{\hyperref[sec:#1]{#1}}
```

then in the appropriate places I just write `(see`\linksec{Drowning}`)` and things all connect up properly. Stop me now if this sounds crazy so far.

The catch is that I don't know what the `\section` command is actually doing. I do have a custom chapter appearance which involves altering `\@makechapterhead`, so I assume that to change how sections work it would be `\@makesectionhead`, but I don't know what the default definition of `\@makesectionhead` is and I can't seem to find it with a google search (probably because I don't know what to search for).

**So the question is:** What do I write to redefine `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` so that they contain labels as above, but without altering their appearance or anything like that. I'm using the Memoir class if it's relevant (which I think it is). I'm also not using any custom appearance for any of the sectioning commands (though I am for `\chapter`), because I like the default appearance of them just fine.

Comment: While it seems there should be a sectional counterpart `\@makesectionhead` to the chapter `\@makechapterhead`, this is not the case. [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) uses a generic `\@startsection` macro to initiate the section (at any level below chapter), and subsequently calls `\M@sect` to build the heading.

Comment: That is both helpful to know and slightly mysterious in design. Though chapters heads are "expected" to do potentially more fancy stuff I guess, so maybe it makes sense.

Comment: @Lokathor This makes sense *only* if the section titles have a very simple structure: one or two words without any accent. And you still have to remember *precisely* the title you gave. IMO it's better to stick with the `\label` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I have understood the question, but here goes.

You can `\renewcommand` the `\section`, `\subsection`, etc commands to add the `\label` of your choosing. The tricky part is that each of these commands take an optional argument (for the headers and `toc`). Luckily, this has already been tackled in a previous question

["Closed" (square) root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29834/closed-square-root-symbol)

Here's a MWE- if I've misunderstood, please let me know

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{\oldsection[#1]{#2}\index{#1}\label{sec:#1}}


\begin{document}

\section[drowning]{Drowning}
Test reference \ref{sec:drowning}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I simplified it a bit because I never use the optional argument to the sectioning commands within this document, and it worked out great!

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}\index{#1}\label{sec:#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Drowning}
Test reference \hyperref[sec:Drowning]{Drowning}
\end{document}

Comment: Actually, that seems to have trashed the ability to use the starred versions of the commands ("\section*{}" and so on) under the normal names. You can still use them under the newly aliased names. eg: instead of \subsection*{Foo} you'd use \oldsubsection*{Foo} If you needed to.

Comment: @Lokathor: Technically you don't need [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) since `\section` is an argument-less macro within [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: you also loose the two extra optional options that `memoir` provides for all its sections commands. A better choice might have been to use the `xparse` package to build a feeding chain for `\oldsection`

Comment: What would that feeding chain look like? I'm not at all familiar with the xparse package.

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me, I'm using `\documentclass{article}`. Do you have any idea as to why?

Answer (score 14):

Imho the easiest way to smuggle a `\label` in is to use `\sectionmark`:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir} % Abstand zwischen 2 Absätzen, kein Einrücken (parindent)
\let\orisectionmark\sectionmark
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\label{sec:#1}\orisectionmark{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Blub}
\section[shortname]{Something very long and perhaps dangerous for a label}
\section{B}
%\section{$\int$} % this breaks!


\ref{sec:shortname}, \ref{sec:B}
\end{document}
```

But be aware that while a `\label` accepts quite a lot types of arguments not everything will work.