# Resize all images in Latex to a percentage width

Tags: graphics, width, tex-core, pandoc

I am auto-generating multiple tex files using pandoc (one tex file for each of my chapters). Pandoc generates this tex code for each image.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{images/flock_of_birds.JPG}
\caption{A flock of storks rush to fill orders during the Baby Boom.}
\end{figure}
```

How can I set the width of all images to a percentage value without directly modifying the generated code? I have attempted to use `\renewcommand\includegraphics`  but my LaTex knowledge falls short.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the existing `\includegraphics` macro to apply any options you desire.

Below, I placed the `\renewcommand` in the main document just so that you can see the effect *before* and *after*.  The `\renewcommand` below ensures that all subsequent usages of `\includegraphics` have the `width=9cm` option applied. Here is a *before* and *after* comparrison:

[image]

### Notes:

- Normally one could use the `\let\OldIncludegraphics{\includegraphics}` syntax, but since `\includegraphics` has an optional parameter we need to use `LetLtxMacro` from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro)
  A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question about a [closed square root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4301).
- The `[demo]` option is used so as to place a black box where the figure would go for demo purposes, in your real usage (when you actually have the figures available), you need to remove this option.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove [demo] option in real usage.
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldIncludegraphics}{\includegraphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{images/flock_of_birds.JPG}
\caption{A flock of storks rush to fill orders during the Baby Boom.}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\OldIncludegraphics[width=9cm, #1]{#2}}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{images/flock_of_birds.JPG}
\caption{A flock of storks rush to fill orders during the Baby Boom.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually `\includegraphics` does not require `\LetLtxMacro`, but using it doesn't hurt. :)

Comment: Just a quick note: The new answer below is for you.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks. Also, nice photography on you flickr page.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter\def\Gin@i{\Gin@ii[scale=0.2]}\makeatother

\begin{document}   
\includegraphics{tiger}
\end{document}
```

scales every image down to 20%. You can also define `width=0.3\linewidth` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Grill:

- In order to overwrite width=42something it **width should be the last argument**: `\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\OldIncludegraphics[#1, width=9cm]{#2}}`
- Note: Method does not scale the image to a percentage but to 9cm. Useful anyhow.

(Disclaimer: Not allowed to make comments in tex.stackexchange)

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to why it should be last. I didn't put it as the last option so that it can be overridden on a per use case, if desired.

Comment: Your point is valid. Indeed, for me I wanted to override the size settings to something small for print where I focused on the text. Of course, one could replace all images and their captions all-together via something `\LetLtxMacro{\OldSubfloat}{\subfloat}
\renewcommand{\subfloat}[2][]{somePicAndCaption}`