# How to get a list of the filenames of the figures embedded in a document

Tags: graphics, packages, printing

I have a TeX document that is embedding a huge amount of figures from a `fig` folder that is full of another humongous amount of other figures.

I would like to move the document along with its figures, but I don't want to take the whole `fig` folder, just the figures in there that are embedded by the document.

Is there a package (or any other way) that allows me to, for example, print out the filenames of all the figures embedded by the document? Something like:

```
fig/figurename1.eps
fig/figurename2.eps
...
etc
```

I could then just copy-paste that list and add some `cp`'s in a plain text file and automate the copy of those files to my desired location by running the file in my shell:

```
$ cp fig/figurename1.eps wherever/fig/
$ cp fig/figurename2.eps wherever/fig/
...
etc
```

Of course this is just an idea, if somebody has an alternative to the "file listing and copy-pasting in a shell file" I would be happy to listen =)

Comment: More of a Unix question than a TeX one, but the following (untested) should work assuming no spaces in your filename: `for name in \`grep includegraphics document.tex | cut -d{ -f2 | cut -d} -f1\`; do cp $name otherfolder; done`

Comment: It tells me `cp: incorrect option -- «{»`

Comment: Odd. Replace the cp with an echo to see what the for loop is using, but the two cut commands should have extracted whatever was between the `{}` characters on an `\includegraphics` line. Or use one of the suggestions below.

Comment: David Carlisle has given a solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205203/95405). Won't it be relevant to this question?

Comment: @manucpp err... this question was asked Sep 26 '14 at 15:34 and already has an accepted answer from Sep 26 '14 at 15:55. The answer you link to is from Oct 8 '14 at 21:27. I didn't have a time machine at the time I asked this.... all are equally valid answers though.

Comment: Sorry. My only intention was to know if both of these answers are correct.  I did not mean to point a flaw in the either the question or the answer. I will delete that comment if it offends you.

Comment: @manucpp ah, sorry. Yes, both answers are correct :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the `\includegraphcs` macro to add to a list and print the list at the end of the document.  The MWE below yields the following output:

```
Figures included were
 images/figA.jpg
 images/figB.png
```

### Notes:

- In this case `\let` would have work as well (as per egreg's comment at [Resize all images in Latex to a percentage width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79726/4301)), but I have gotten used to using `\LetLtxMacro` from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) for macros which have optional parameters.
  A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question about a [closed square root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4301).
- The `[demo]` option is used so as to place a black box where the figure would go for demo purposes, in your real usage (when you actually have the figures available), you need to remove this option.
- If you wanted to you could use `\immediate\write18` and execute the `cp` shell command within the `\foreach` loop and have a directory at the end of typesetting which has the images that were included. No further processing would be required.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove [demo] option in real usage.
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{pgffor}


%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time
\newcommand\FigList{}
\newcommand\AddFigToList[1]{\edef\FigList{\FigList#1,}}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldIncludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
    \AddFigToList{#2}%
    \OldIncludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\ShowListOfFigures}{%
    \typeout{Figures included were}%
    \foreach \x in \FigList {%
        %\par\x% <-- uncomment if you want the list in the PDF as well
        \typeout{ \x}
    }%
}
\AtEndDocument{\ShowListOfFigures}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{images/figA.jpg}

\includegraphics{images/figB.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help. ...l.25 \usepackage{letltxmacro} ? `

Comment: @XiruxNefer: I assume that is in your actual use case and not the MWE above. Did you remove the `demo` option?

Comment: I removed the `demo` option now, and it compiles, but it doesn't show the list of embedded figures. I guess it should be the last thing in the document, just after the references list, but I have searched the whole document and there is nothing printed =(

Comment: @XiruxNefer: If you want it printed in the doc the uncomment the line `\par\x`.  I designed it to be printed at the end in the log/console output which is what `\typeout` does - easier to cut and paste from there.

Comment: Oh my, it is also not printing anything to the terminal =( =( =(. Agh, sorry for all the time you are investing in this. Infinite thanks. I'll try uncommenting the line `\par\x`.

Comment: IT WORKED. 368 figures so far (the document has around 500 pages, he he he). THANK YOU!

Answer (score 6):

`pdflatex` provides the flag `-recorder`, that writes a `.fls` file. Everything marked `INPUT` there, are files, that it opened during processing.
`latexmk` uses the flag `-deps` or `-deps-out=FILENAME` to show the decencies and in the last case also store those in a `make` formatted `FILENAME`.

Comment: This is tremendously useful !

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, something like this will do, without modifying the source:

```
strace -fe open  make 2>&1  1>/dev/null | grep plots | sed 's/.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/' > plots.list
```

Where :

- `make` is the command you use to build your output (could be some variation of   `pdflatex file.tex`).
- `strace` displays the syscalls. With the options we are providing, we keep only the "open" syscalls (`-e` option) in order to get the figures that are inserted (as well as other opened files foe now). The `-f` options is to display syscalls of subprocesses and the redirections are to keep only the strace output.
- `grep plots` selects the lines containing a common string in the path ("plots" in this case).
- `sed` selects what is inside the quotes.
- The final redirection dumps the result in a file.

You may get duplicate filenames this way, but could be good enough depending what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `perl` script on CTAN, [texdepend](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdepend?lang=en) that does all of this and more. It handles all sorts of internal and external dependencies, and can generate the information in `Makefile`, `perl` or 1-per-line format.

```
>texdepend
Find LaTex dependencies, Version: 0.96, Michael Friendly (friendly@yorku.ca)
Usage: C:\batchfiles\texdepend.pl <options> texfile[.tex]
  where <options> may be abbreviated to unique truncations, and are:
   -help               print this measly help
   -expand             expand package/include file to full path names
   -format = make      print dependencies in Makefile format
             perl      print in the form of perl assignments (LatexMk)
             1         print one per line (with # separators)
   -ignore = list      list of file types to be ignored in .log [default: fd]
   -out = filename     send output to filename
   -print =            Any one or more of i (includes) p (packages)
                       f (figs) b (bibfiles) s (styles) d (all dependencies)
   -styles = list      list of file types for  from .log [default: sty]
   -verbose
```