# How to make \includegraphics to print image path to the image?

Tags: includegraphics

I have written large (large, by my understanding, 40 pages) document with a lot of images. I need to make a beamer presentation, and I need to use photos from this document.

So I want to open this document, see the text and images, and make the presentation out of them. If I need any image from the document, it would be good to see it's path or at least name on the disk (or `<path>`).

How to make `\includegraphics[<opts>]{<path>}` to to print image path `<path>` to the image itself? So I could open this document and see where to find image source without browsing the latex code. Is there some workaround?

Comment: Most editors have a search functionality where you can double or ctrl click in the pdf and it will take you to that area of the source.  You can also pass the `draft` option to `graphicx` (or your documentclass), and the images will be replaced by their paths (so you'd need two copies of the pdf - one with images and one with paths).  (How bad is your tex code?  I can usually ctrl f a choice phrase and get at most three matches in my entire document.)  Do any of those possibilities work for you?

Comment: @Teepeemm ctr-click wont work for me - I use neovim (editor) and skim (pdf-viewer) setup, and all this on Mac OS. For some reason vimtex (neovim plugin that does latex things) wont speak to skim properly and I cant use backward-search. What about `draft` option, it is and option, but It is not so comfortable to use 2 documents instead of 1 with titles and images in one. Thanks for notes.

Comment: You can do something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203309/ but then simpler, just print `#2` instead of adding it to a list, or maybe `\detokenize{#2}` if there are special characters in the filename.

Comment: @@Marijn Thank You! I made next thing: ```\LetLtxMacro{\OldIncludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
    \OldIncludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
 \vspace{-2cm}%
 \center{\smash{\colorbox{red}{\textcolor{white}{\tiny \tt \detokenize{#2}}}}}%
 \vspace{2cm}%
}
``` Could you make this an answer so I will mark it as resolved? This works as intended.