# Adding a symbol inside the link to a reference

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to add a symbol (like an arrow) behind a reference, editing the `\ref` command, something like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\newref}[1]{\ref{#1}\,\ding{230}}

\begin{document}
As we can see in figure \newref{photo} ...

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[]{./figures/photo.jpg}
\caption{} \label{photo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the PDF, it works clicking in the number "1" of the text "As we can see in figure 1 (arrow) ...", but I would like to achieve that clicking in the arrow brings me also to the place where the photo is. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Good MWE! But avoid the `[H]` option. ;-)

Comment: (A quick solution that I thought of was incorrect. Then, I thought this question was a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102724/34551 . They are related, but OP wants something slightly different, so I removed my comments.)

Comment: I need to put the [H] option, otherwise the figure goes to another page, to the previous chapter. I put all the figures in an annex at the end of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this thanks to the `\ref*` command, which, according to hyperref's manual, create a reference with the correct number, but without link.

I also enclosed a solution with `autoref`, which I recommend (it automatically "guess" the type of the reference you are making, e.g., Theorem, Lemma, Figure, Chapter, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\newref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\ref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}

\newcommand{\newautoref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}

\begin{document}
As we can see in figure \newref{photo}

But in \autoref{photo}, or in \newautoref{photo}

\begin{figure}
Toto
\caption{My caption} \label{photo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand{\newref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\ref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}
```

- `\hyperref{<label>}{<free text>}` creates a link similar to `\ref{<label>}` using the same label `<label>`, but the second argument takes a free text.
- The star form `\ref*` creates a reference without link. This avoids a nested link, the reference is already inside the link, created by `\hyperref`.
- I recommend package `caption` or `hypcap` to move the link target to the beginning of the `figure` environment. Otherwise the link points to the caption.

Comment: Why do you protect the first argument of `\hyperref` with `[{#1}]`?

Comment: @Clément TeX only checks the matching of curly braces (characters with category code 1 and 2). If `#1` contains a closing `]` outside of groups, then this is found instead of the outer `]`, because it comes first.

Comment: Indeed, without that protection, a label `phot]o` produces a `Hyper reference `phot' on page 1 undefined`.

Comment: Works perfect. Only an insignificant comment: for adding the word "Figure" in the link (red box), I need to add it in the definition command: `
\newcommand{\newautoref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{Figure\,\autoref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}`

Comment: I guess you wanted to comment on my answer, and not on the one from Heiko, who do not mention `autoref`. If this is the case, just try to compile the code I'm giving: the word "Figure" should be inside the link when using `\newcommand{\newautoref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}`. Please edit your question if you have a more specific problem.

Comment: @Clément Yes, I wanted to comment your answer but I didn' know where to place the comment and I thought it would be better for the thread to comment in the most recent answer because Heiko also cites the line you wrote -sorry if I did bad-. In fact, with two solutions you provide -\newautoref and \newref-, I need to put the word inside the definition command, may be due to the language I use, spanish... So, both:`\newcommand{\newref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{fig.\,\ref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}
\newcommand{\newautoref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{fig.\,\autoref*{#1}\,\ding{230}}}` work and the problem is solved.