# Fixing tikz in cventry of moderncv

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, moderncv

As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99316/symbol-for-external-links), I use symbols drawn with tikz to indicate hyperlinks in my cv.
However when used in the `cventry` command of the [modern cv package](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), this caused an error.
Here is the minimal non-working example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,color,final]{moderncv}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\ExternalLink}{%
  \tikz[x=1.2ex, y=1.2ex, baseline=-0.05ex]{% 
    \begin{scope}[x=1ex, y=1ex]
      \clip (-0.1,-0.1) 
      --++ (-0, 1.2) 
      --++ (0.6, 0) 
      --++ (0, -0.6) 
      --++ (0.6, 0) 
      --++ (0, -1);
      \path[draw, 
        line width = 0.5, 
      rounded corners=0.5] 
      (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw, line width = 0.5] (0.5, 0.5) 
    -- (1, 1);
    \path[draw, line width = 0.5] (0.6, 1) 
    -- (1, 1) -- (1, 0.6);
  }
}

\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}

\firstname{FirstName}
\familyname{Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section}
\cventry{2014}{\href{http://example.com/ \ExternalLink}{My great position}}{My great company}{My great city}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Edit following [Salim Bou](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/54817/salim-bou)'s answer.
The following works

`\cventry{2014}{\href{http://example.com/}{My great position \ExternalLink}}{My great company}{My great city}{}{}`

(The symbol shoulb be placed in the string not in the url).

However this still produces an error

`\cventry{2014}{My great position}{\href{http://example.com/}{My great company \ExternalLink}}{My great city}{}{}`

Looking at the log the error looks quite similar. Latex is complaining about some error message being undefined.

Comment: You can use `\cventry{2014}{My great position}{\href{http://example.com/}{My great company \protect\ExternalLink}}{My great city}{}{}`

Answer (score 5):

You need to include your symbol like this

```
\cventry{2014}{\href{http://example.com/}{\ExternalLink My great position}}
{My great company}{My great city}{}{}
```

Comment: Ok this solves the initial problem but there is still a bug. I edited my question in regard of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since it's the first result that appears when searching for `"moderncv tikz error"`, here's my take.

Use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` to define the TikZ macro. That's it. See [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/) if you are interested in understanding *why*.