# Spacing after a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I'm trying to add an external link symbol (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294990/163482) to href but for some reason the spacing after the symbol is wrong when I redefine the href command. What would the right way to do it (and what would be the right amount of space)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref}
\newcommand{\ExternalLink}{%
  \tikz[x=1.2ex, y=1.2ex, baseline=-0.5ex, scale=0.75]{% 
    \begin{scope}[x=1ex, y=1ex]
      \clip (-0.1,-0.1) 
       --++ (-0, 1.2) 
       --++ (0.6, 0) 
       --++ (0, -0.6) 
       --++ (0.6, 0) 
       --++ (0, -1);
      \path[draw=black, line width = 0.5,
            rounded corners=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw=black, line width = 0.5] (0.5, 0.5) -- (1, 1);
    \path[draw=black, line width = 0.5] (0.6, 1)   -- (1, 1) -- (1, 0.6);
  }
}

\let\orighref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\orighref{#1}{#2}$\,$\ExternalLink}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text \href{http://google.com}{link} some more text.\\
Some text \orighref{http://google.com}{link}$\,$\ExternalLink some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write:

```latex
Some text \orighref{http://google.com}{link}$\,$\ExternalLink some more text.
```

the space after `\ExternalLink` is ignored by TeX, because `\ExternalLink` is a control sequence whose name ends with a letter. On the contrary, with:

```latex
Some text \href{http://google.com}{link} some more text.
```

there is a space token after `{link}`, and it is not ignored. It contributes an interword space to the horizontal list under construction. That is why you see a larger space in the first case of your example (second case here). In order to get rid of this additional space, you can either write:

```latex
Some text \href{http://google.com}{link}some more text.
```

or use `\ignorespaces` in your redefinition of `\href` so as to ignore spaces following in the input (`\ignorespaces` expands tokens from the input stream until it finds an unexpandable token that is not a 〈space token〉, according to the TeX grammar):

```latex
\renewcommand*{\href}[2]{\orighref{#1}{#2}$\,$\ExternalLink\ignorespaces}
```

But actually, you don't want to use any of these suggestions. This is because in your `\ExternalLink` command, there is a most probably unwanted space:

```latex
\newcommand{\ExternalLink}{%

...

    \path[draw=black, ...] ... ;
  } % <------- here, remove the space
}
```

So, your `\ExternalLink` command unconditionally adds this space after the icon. I believe this is unwanted when the hyperlink is followed by a comma or a period, for instance. Therefore I'd remove this space; then you don't need `\ignorespaces` anymore.

Also note that you don't need to be in math mode in order to use `\,`; it produces a `\thinspace` when used outside of math mode. So, you can do something like:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\href}[2]{\orighref{#1}{#2}\,\ExternalLink}
```

Other suggestion: you may want to include the icon inside the clickable link:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\href}[2]{\orighref{#1}{#2\,\ExternalLink}}
```

I used `\renewcommand*` because the arguments of `\href` most probably shouldn't contain `\par` tokens; this makes finding errors easier.

Note: there won't be a line break at the `\,`, because this macro expands to `\thinspace` in non-math mode, which itself expands to a `\kern`, and there can be a break at a `\kern` only if it's immediately followed by glue—which isn't the case here, as `\ExternalLink` starts with a box: the Ti*k*Z picture.

Final remark: your links are going to make TeX work hard on the Ti*k*Z picture every time you use this redefined `\href` (i.e., for every hyperlink). Since the icon is always the same, there is a way to save on compilation time: save the picture *once* inside a box, then use the box whenever you need it. That is very cheap on computing resources. All in all, here is my suggestion (I added a picture with a caption because of our discussion in the comments—the `\usebox` command doesn't need to be `\protect`ed, as the example shows):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % 'hidelinks' removes the border around links

\newsavebox{\ExternalLinkIcon}

\begin{lrbox}{\ExternalLinkIcon}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.2ex, y=1.2ex, baseline=-0.5ex, scale=0.75]
    \begin{scope}[x=1ex, y=1ex]
      \clip (-0.1,-0.1)
       --++ (-0, 1.2)
       --++ (0.6, 0)
       --++ (0, -0.6)
       --++ (0.6, 0)
       --++ (0, -1);
      \path[draw=black, line width = 0.5,
            rounded corners=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw=black, line width = 0.5] (0.5, 0.5) -- (1, 1);
    \path[draw=black, line width = 0.5] (0.6, 1)   -- (1, 1) -- (1, 0.6);
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- important!
\end{lrbox}

\let\orighref\href

\renewcommand*{\href}[2]{%
  \orighref{#1}{#2\,\usebox{\ExternalLinkIcon}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text \href{http://example.com}{link} some more text. Spacing is also fine
before a \href{http://example.com}{comma}, as you can see. Periods are fine
too, of course---we don't have to do anything special.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  This is the figure contents.
  \caption{A caption containing a \href{http://example.com}{hyperlink}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, works nicely but I just realized the tikz part was not working inside a caption. It needs  a \DeclareRobustCommand{\ExternaLink...}

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that a caption is subject to `\protected@write` for the list of figures or list of tables, and  `\protected@write` tries to expand everything that is neither `\protected` nor preceded by `\protect`. You can use `\newrobustcmd*` from the `etoolbox` package, that is slightly better.

Comment: There was a spurious space at the end of your `\ExternalLink` command. This changes everything! Please reread my answer...