# Suffixing a URL with that domain's favicon (custom external link symbol)

Tags: hyperref, urls, fontawesome, icon

In an [existing thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99316/203081), it is shown how to suffix a `hyperref` URL with the generic "external URL" symbol. In [another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190927/linkedin-logo-in-latex), the top answer shows how to use FontAwesome for inserting the favicons/logos of various companies into LaTeX documents.

I want to combine these two as follows: I want to get the same result of that first thread, *except* for domains whose favicons are registered in the preamble, where the generic symbol is substituted by that favicon for all calls to `\href` that use that domain.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% ... the logic that defines \faExternalLink as the default suffix for \href ...
% ... some logic that defines \registerDomain[2] ...

\registerDomain{github.com}{\faGithub}
\registerDomain{twitter.com}{\faTwitterSquare}

\begin{document}
\href{https://twitter.com/elonmusk}{Link to Twitter/X's CEO}

\href{https://docs.github.com/en/get-started}{Link to GitHub's documentation}

\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth}{Link to a miscellaneous webpage}
\end{document}
```

Note that the last two URLs use a subdomain. The middle one still needs to use the superdomain's icon.

### Implementation ideas

If the domains and icons were hardcoded inside a command definition, it would probably be sufficient to use a conditional that [checks if a substring is present in a URL string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26870/203081), although that could theoretically lead to spurious matches (in something like `github.com.mywebsite.org`) which might require a proper URL parser.

Here, we'll need some kind of global dictionary from domain to icon name.