# Replicating an environment to another and making changes to original

Tags: environments

I would like to define a new environment with the name `oldproof` which is basically the `proof` environment and then make changes to the proof environment. I would still like to be able to access the original proof environment using `oldproof`. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What kind of changes would you make to the `proof` environment? There might be different ways than maintaining two different environments that could give much more flexibility.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An environment `<name>` will basically translate into two commands: `\<name>` and `\end<name>` and the former will deal with eventual argument for the environment. One option then would be to `\let` the original commands to some other ones; however, since `proof` has an optional argument, one cannot simply use `\let` for `\proof`; additional precautions must be taken and one can use `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package.

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\oldproof\proof
\let\endoldproof\endproof
```

A complete example (I introduced two font changes to the original environment, just for illustration purposes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\LetLtxMacro\oldproof\proof
\let\endoldproof\endproof

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\sffamily% NEW
  \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \bfseries% NEW
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is a modified proof environment.
\end{proof}

\begin{oldproof}
This is the original proof environment.
\end{oldproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding commands with an optional argument and `\LetLtxMacro` valuable information is provided in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88007/3954) to [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/3954) and, in more detail, in [this other answer of his](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/3954) to  ["Closed" (square) root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29834/3954).

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you prefer to use `\LetLtxMacro` in the first line instead of simply using `\let`.

Comment: @set_kwr I was just adding the explanation; the problem is that `proof` has an optional argument which will be an optional argument for `\proof`; for commands with optional arguments, `\let` is not a safe option.