# Undesired spacing before \sqrt[n]{x}, proper way to fix?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[ J(\sqrt[n]{x}) \]
\end{document}
```

compiles into this:

[image: screenshot]

The spacing after the opening parentheses is ugly. What's the proper way to fix this?

Comment: `J(\!\sqrt[n]{x})`?

Comment: @Manuel: Don't I have to do that where I do `\sqrt`? Doesn't seem like a good solution...

Comment: @Mehrdad Small adjustments are necessary for such cases; you should also add `\,` between the radical and the closing parenthesis: `J(\!\sqrt[n]{x}\,)`

Comment: @Mehrdad When you finish your document: Find & Replace `(\sqrt` by `(\!\sqrt` and that's probably it.

Comment: @Manuel: I think you're completely missing the point of my question.

Comment: Well, the question to me says “What's the proper way to fix this” and my answer was “Do it manually”. And I added the Find & Replace because it removes lot's of work from that solution. If what you are looking for a redefinition of `\sqrt` command, may be it's doable, but it doesn't seem too obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is really a difference between `J(\sqrt{x})` and `J(\sqrt[n](x))`, that's not justified by the root index: a small horizontal space is added in the latter case.

You can get the same width by patching the `\sqrt` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\sqrt}{\@sqrt}{{\mspace{-2.9274mu}\@sqrt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$J(\sqrt{x})$}\the\wd0

\sbox0{$J(\sqrt[n]{x})$}\the\wd0

\[ J(\sqrt{x})+J(\sqrt[n]{x})\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

There will still be some more space in script style, though.

However, proper typesetting of this requires a thin space after the radical:

```
J(\sqrt[n]{x}\,)
```

so the output would be

[image]

Such adjustment can't be provided automatically, because it depends on the symbol following the radical.

Comment: @Mehrdad Probably @barbarabeeton will see this and add it to the list of adjustments for `amsmath`.

Comment: That's awesome :) By the way, is there a way to avoid the magic `-2.9274mu` number? Where did it come from? (Can I calculate it based on something else?)

Comment: @Mehrdad Computed with trial and error. It's not really the best patch, but at least it works in normal size. Be careful that with different fonts the amount of adjustment might not be the best.

Comment: Ah I see, okay.

Comment: Only just now noticed this answer. Out of idle curiosity: What was the reason for choosing `\mspace{-2.9274mu}` rather than `\mkern-2.9274mu` as the spacing adjustment directive?

Comment: @Mico Because `\mspace` is a higher level command.