# \sqrt but with a vertical drop at the end

Tags: math-mode

I have a formula

```
$$\sqrt{t_{i + 1} - t_i }\epsilon_{ij}$$
```

But when rendered, it looks a little unclear since the epsilon is not adequately separated from the square root.

I'm reluctant to reorder the terms in any way. What I'm after is some way of putting a short vertical line after the square root symbol (say 1/4 height attached to the horizontal bar) which is a common thing to do.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: This might help: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Roots

Comment: See also (possible dupe): ["Closed" (square) root symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29834)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the "closed" form of the square-root symbol -- which some find "unnecessary and ugly" -- you could (a) insert a "thinspace" (`\,`) right before `\epsilon` or (b) change the notation of the square-root term to the `(....)^{0.5}` form.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$ \sqrt{t_{i + 1} - t_i }\,\epsilon_{ij} $
or
$ (t_{i + 1} - t_i )^{0.5}\epsilon_{ij} $
\end{document}
```