# How can I reduce the gap between left and right of \cdot with a macro?

Tags: macros, math-operators

Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
%\LetLtxMacro{\oldcdot}{\cdot}
%\renewcommand{\cdot}{\!\cdot\!} <-- Like this
\begin{document}
$3\cdot 10^8$ m/s
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the following output.

[image]

However `\cdot` has many spaces between left and right. How do I get the following image? Should I have a macro?

[image]

Related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29838/33075

Comment: `$3{\cdot} 10^8$ m/s` kills the `\mathbin` space before and after `\cdot`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, How simple!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\cdot` is defined in `fontmath.ltx` with:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cdot}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"01}
```

which means it is a `bin`ary operator (`\mathbin`) so it will have an extra space before and after as other binary operators, such as `+` and `-`.

TeX will not insert that space if you “hide” `\cdot` within braces:

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$3{\cdot} 10^8$ m/s
\end{document}
```

If you will use that symbol multiple times you can define an `ord`inary math symbol (`\mathord`) with the same glyph as `\cdot`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mdot}{\mathord}{symbols}{"01}
\begin{document}
$3\mdot 10^8$ m/s
\end{document}
```

or you can redefine `\cdot` with the same command.

Comment: +1 Or call it `\mdot` for "multiplication dot"

Comment: I largely prefer this answer since it addresses the general case of spacings before and after `\cdot` which IMHO are way too large (and mostly encourages one to just put several characters together without `\cdot` between them, *e.g.* `2jk\pi` instead of `2 \cdot j \cdot k \cdot \pi`, which is - I believe - quite bad practice). Anyway, the simple `\DeclareMathSymbol{\cdot}{\mathord}{symbols}{"01}` did the trick for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 16):

For this I recommend `siunitx`, that ensures uniformity in numbers and units.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  exponent-product={{\cdot}}, % double brace for avoiding the space
  per-mode=symbol,
}

\begin{document}

\SI{3e8}{\meter\per\second} % long form

\SI{3e8}{m/s} % abbreviated form

\SI[per-mode=reciprocal]{3e8}{\meter\per\second} % long form

\end{document}
```

Note that it's easy to change from a representation to another, when the long form is used (which is recommended).

Also this has the advantage that you just need to change the option in the preamble if you change your mind about how to represent that product.

[image]

The same effect can be obtained with the option `tight-spacing`, which however will act also on all binary operations, for instance uncertainties.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  exponent-product=\cdot,
  tight-spacing,
  per-mode=symbol,
}

\begin{document}

\SI{3e8}{\meter\per\second} % long form

\SI{3e8}{m/s} % abbreviated form

\SI[per-mode=reciprocal]{3e8}{\meter\per\second} % long form

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now _this_ is the proper way to do it :-)

Comment: +1. Instead of hard-coding the tightly-spaced behavior, one could also run `\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot, tight-spacing=true}`. Then, if at some point in the document it becomes necessary to switch to non-tight spacing, one can simply execute `\sisetup{tight-spacing=false}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint. I added it, but noted that this acts also in other places.